# create expression index on postgres timestamp

Tags: postgresql, indexing, timestamp

Simple table

```sql
create table x(t timestamp);
```

in many places  i need to say

```
where extract(year from t) and extract(quarter from t)
```

can we state an expression index here ? and how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below SQL:

```
create index idx_cust_test on x(extract(year from t), extract(quarter from t));
```

The whole script can be checked on:
[fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3jC8PGeZZEuty3XVq8gdzz/3)